# Adding time to url address

Tags: objective-c

I try to add time informations to an url address.

example:

http://www.test.de/output/iphone.txt?%Y%m%d%H%M%S

like this.

This was my first try:

First i tried to recieve the current time:

```
    NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date]; //  aktuelles Datum und die Uhrzeit
    NSString *strDate =  [[currentDate
                           dateWithCalendarFormat:@"%Y%m%d%H%M%S" timeZone:nil]  description];

+
    NSString *siteString = @"http://www.test.de/output/iphone.txt";
NSURL *siteURL  = [NSURL URLWithString:siteString];            
    NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:siteURL encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];
```

Now I have two variables, `strDate` and `siteString`.
I want to combine these strings, at the end I want to have the following string:

```
NSString *link = [siteString "+" ? "+" strDate]
```

that string should look like:

http://www.test.de/output/iphone.txt?YYYYmmddHHMMss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a standard string formatting function to concatenate the two pieces together...

```
   [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?%@",siteString,strDate]
```